# How can I draw a line beside a boxplot

Tags: r, draw, boxplot

How can I draw a line beside a boxplot for show place of a value

something like this red line:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try arrows function:

```
arrows(x1,y1,x2,y2)
```